# why don't mysql implement kill idle transaction like percona server?

Tags: mysql, transactions, kill, percona

percona server:

https://github.com/percona/percona-server/pull/1164

Current kill idle transaction feature implementation works at a low InnoDB transaction list level, periodically scanning it and killing the old ones.

Lixun Peng proposed re-implementing this by setting a different socket read timeout value instead (bug 907719). Such implementation has several advantages:
- much simpler code, getting rid of crashing bugs in the current one (bug 1166744, bug 1179136)
- works with any storage engine, not only InnoDB.

On user level, introduce a new server variable kill_idle_transaction. Make the old innodb_kill_idle_transaction variable its deprecated alias, to be removed in 8.0.

Comment: This is best asked on https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=67906 (note that Percona patch cannot be taken MySQL directly due to their contribution rules).

Comment: thanks，because registration is Annoying，so I asked here.

Comment: @褚华兴 Could you please mark this as answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying Laurynas's answer here so this question can be marked "answered": This is best asked on bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=67906 (note that Percona patch cannot be taken MySQL directly due to their contribution rules). – Laurynas Biveinis